# Find indexes of selected element in nestled lists

Tags: python

Need to find indexes for element '.' in nestled list, and add them to new list.
Outcome should look like:

```
board = [
    ['X', '0', '.'],
    ['.', 'X', '0'],
    ['0', '.', 'X']]

coordinates = list()
for r, row in enumerate(board):
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        if "." in board[r][c]:
            coordinates.append([r, c])

print(coordinates)
```

is there any easier method, maybe list comprehension ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension, but because it's nested, it's not much simpler.

```
coordinates = [
    [r, c]
    for r, row in enumerate(board)
    for c, cell in enumerate(row)
    if cell == "."
    ]
```

BTW, calling your strings `col` is confusing, and so is using `in` since you're trying to check for equality, not containment. So I changed those bits.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension!

```
board = [
    ['X', '0', '.'],
    ['.', 'X', '0'],
    ['0', '.', 'X']]

coordinates = [[r, c] for r, l in enumerate(board) 
                      for c, entry in enumerate(l) if entry == '.']

print(coordinates)
```